# Firebase not being downloaded by Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

First of all I´d like to say that I am new to Firebase, so sorry if my question is basic.

I´ve followed the [Firebase official tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html).

So this is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pru"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
```

It runs OK, but when I try to use `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` in Java, it will simply not give me the option to import the Firebase library.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll say, try to rebuild your project.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier It worked buddy,  you place that as an answer and I´ll mark it as the good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rebuild your project :

Build -> Rebuild Project

Sometimes Android Studio doesn't indexing all the files.